# Export user roles with Sonata admin

Tags: symfony, symfony4, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I'm using `SonataAdmin` and `FosUserBundle` with Symfony 4.
I want to use the export feature to export whole users' data in CSV, JSON ...
When a trigger the export, the roles column in the file is empty or null.

In the UserAdmin class, I have overridden the getExportFields function with the call of a specific method to get the role as explained in this post. [Sonata admin export fields with collection fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442732/sonata-admin-export-fields-with-collection-fields)
But it doesn't work.

Example in my case:

```
 public function getExportFields()
 {
    return [
        'id',
        'username',
        'roles' => 'rolesExported'
    ];
 }
```

And in my User Entity:

```
public function getRolesExported()
{
    $exportedRoles = [];
    foreach ($this->getRealRoles() as $role) {

        $exportedRoles[] = $role->__toString();
    }

    return $this->rolesExported = implode(' - ', $exportedRoles);
}
```

In this case, when I trigger the export, my web browser shows the error

> 'website is inaccessible' with no error in the dev.log.

When I delete `'roles' => 'rolesExported'` in the `getExportFields` function, the export is well triggered.

- SonataAdmin version : 3.35
- FosUserBundle version : 2.1.2
- Symfony version: 4.3.2 (I know that I need to update it)

Comment: you did something, where you don't want to show the code for, you use a different symfony version, that post is 2 years old, there could be a number of reasons why it doesn't work anymore. Please show some code, and shortly elaborate what "it doesn't work" precisely means! (could mean anything from "errors" to "wrong output" to "no effect at all")

Comment: I have added some details to understand the issue. Hope it will help.

Comment: as a side note: you should really find out, where the errors are put. are you running this on a proper web server? are you running this on dev environment? on a web server, the php log might be in [symfony]/var/log/(prod/dev).log, or /var/log/php_errors(.log) or /var/log/php-fpm/errors.log or some other general log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the `__toString()` call causes a problem.

although the post you used as your inspiration explicitly says that it wants to export collections, I assume you might want to export an array.

Since I don't know the type of your `$role` objects, for debugging purposes first replace `$role->__toString()` with `gettype($role)`, so the line is:
`$exportedRoles[] = gettype($role);`

I see three cases here:

1. `object` or for multiple roles `object - object - ...`, in that case, you should select a method of Role that returns a proper string or create one at that place, like `$exportedRoles[] = $role->getName();`
2. `string` or for multiple roles `string - string - ...`, in that case your "real" roles is just an array, and you can replace the contents of your function with `return implode(' - ', $this->getRealRoles());`
3. `array` or for multiple roles `array - array - ...`, in that case you have an array for each role, and those don't provide `__toString`. Select a method to construct the exported role, like `$exportedRoles[] = $role['name'];`

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I have the roles data in the csv output.

Comment: @chaillouvincent which one was it?

Comment: the role object is as string (not really good documented in the bundle). So i have deleted the toString() call and everything was ok after that.